# How to get the id of a post from a URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a URL that is formatted like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/post/5dc07270e7179a5293d14e70
```

The part after /post/ contains an id as you see. I managed to obtain it by doing the following:

```
const path = this.props.location.pathname;
const postId = path.slice(6, 30);
```

Is there a better way of obtaining that id in React?

Comment: If using react-router-dom use the prop `match` injected through `withRouter`, and then access `match.params`. Of course the `Route` must be defined in a way to accept that param

Comment: Re *"...contains an id as you see. I **managed to obtain it** by doing the following"*: Does that actually output the ID? Doesn't it output "`/localhost:3000/post/5dc`"?

Answer (score 1):

You can `split` on "/" and `slice` the result with a negative index (if the id is always the last part of the path).

```js
console.log("http://localhost:3000/post/5dc07270e7179a5293d14e70".split("/").slice(-1)[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you can preprocess that string and get id out from there, but for the brighter future you should do it another way.

An example of better use is **[react-router-dom](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start)** since it lets you define parameters in your URL, and you can easily get that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use withRouter to get the history and location details in the props. From there you can split the url by '/' and the length - 1 will be your id.

Or you can go raw javascript

```
let url = window.location.href.split('/')
console.log(url[url.length - 1])
```

If the id is not specified in the url like this

```
?id=yourid
```

Then the id must have to be at the end of the url for this to work.